# PHP is automatically removing whitespace I want to keep

Tags: php, special-characters

I have a string I want to process which looks like this:

```
    HHHHHHHHHHHHHHGGGHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH GGGGGG TTTTT  SHHHHHH HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH
```

Note how there are multiple spaces between characters. The number of spaces is important, and thus I don't want them to be discarded. When I read this line from a file using php, it prints the following:

```
HHHHHHHHHHHHHHGGGHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH GGGGGG TTTTT SHHHHHH HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH
```

Maintaining only a single space where there were several before. How can I stop PHP from doing this?

Ultimately I want to substring the entire thing into an array of individual characters but I need the array position to be preserved.

Thank you!

EDIT: Example of what I'm talking about:

[image]

Comment: What are you viewing this on?

Comment: Textfiles and firefox?

Comment: I bet the spaces are there in source. You'll have to replace with `&nbsp;` to see it in browser

Comment: Its probably your browser who removes the spaces, not php

Comment: Not sure what textfiles is, but firefox may well not render multiple spaces. Check view-source.

Comment: If the spaces aren't showing in view source, you need to provide your PHP that's dealing with the file.

Comment: Yes, you guys were correct. I was printing an imploded array and I guess the browser was rendering out the extra spaces. When I print_r the entire array, it shows properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace it with the html entity for a non breaking space to view it rendered in browser's html

```
<?php
$str = '    HHHHHHHHHHHHHHGGGHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH GGGGGG TTTTT  SHHHHHH HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH';

$str = str_replace(' ','&nbsp;',$str);

echo $str;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will accept this answer ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

If you're viewing it with a browser you could use HTML to keep the formatting intact. For instance:

```
echo '<pre>  HHHHHHHHHHHHHHGGGHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH GGGGGG TTTTT  SHHHHHH HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH</pre>';
```

See: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp

I think `<code>` might also work.